# Read CSV wit specific columns and rest into last column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have set of columnar data, separated by spaces

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

What is needed is to read it as CSV, separated by white spaces, but only 5 first columns to be in, rest of the text should be single column, something like this

```
|Lorem|ipsum|dolor|sit|amet,|consectetur adipiscing elit|
```

Last column should contain anything beyond first 5, so there would be variable number of words and spaces

No problem to read it as CSV one column per word.

But I have a bit of a struggle to get variable word count tail into single column.

Any help is greatly appreciated

I did read it line-by-line and parse and insert into Pandas DF, but this is/was slow. So anything with read_csv() or similar would be nice.

Basically, log file

```
|ID|Datetime|Level|Recovered|Place|Message

 1  20230102 WARN  Yes       func1 Something wrong
 2  20230103 ERROR No        func2 Something really bad
```

Comment: can you post a more representative fragment (a more few rows)?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Sure, it's just basically a log file, see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also use [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) but with a *regex separator* :

```
import io
​
s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
​
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep=r"\s(?=[^,]*,)|,\s", engine="python")
​
```

​Output :

```
print(df.columns)

Index(['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'consectetur adipiscing elit'], 
        dtype='object')
```

> [[*Regex demo*](https://regex101.com/r/rCKhVU/1)]

***Update*** :

For fun, you can use this regex approach to target the first five whitespaces :

```
import csv

with open("input.csv") as csvfile:
    col_names = next(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="|"))
    df = pd.read_csv("input.csv", sep=r"(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)|\|",
                     engine="python").dropna(axis=1).set_axis(col_names, axis=1)
```

Otherwise, use [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) :

```
with open("input.csv") as csvfile:
    col_names = next(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="|"))
    df = (pd.read_csv("input.csv", header=None, skiprows=1)
              [0].str.split(r"\b\s+", n=5, expand=True)
              .set_axis(col_names, axis=1)
```

Output :

```
   ID  Datetime  Level Recovered  Place               Message
0   1  20230102   WARN       Yes  func1       Something wrong
1   2  20230103  ERROR        No  func2  Something really bad
```

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but how regex knows I need 5 columns and collate everything else?

Comment: Do you always have the comma (`,`) right after the fifth whitespace ?

Comment: No, have semicolon in one of the columns, but that's it

Comment: And the comma comes always right before* the fifth whitespace ?

Comment: Is your solution based on precise comma position? Well, that might not work in general. I just looking into regex, and cannot see how it could just count columns. I might be completely wrong

Comment: Why you put a comma in your example if you don’t have it in your real dataset ? The regex pattern is based on the position of the comma so please share an example that describes the most your dataset. Otherwise, use *@MattDMo’s* approach.

Comment: I updated my post, example is at the bottom. Sorry for the confusion. Still wondering if one could really count words and columns with regex

Comment: I updated my answer with two more approaches.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument of [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is the number of times to perform the split.

```
s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
"|".join(s.split(" ", 5))
```

yields

```
'Lorem|ipsum|dolor|sit|amet,|consectetur adipiscing elit'
```

Combine this with [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to create either a temp CSV file or an in-memory `str` object, then pass that to `pd.read_csv`.

Answer (score 1):

sample.csv

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
CSV Test Say Hello world from python
```

in Python,
import data and add transpose, it is easier to edit value according to index by row than by column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', header = None, sep = " ").T
```

print 5 first columns (in this case it would be a row)

```
print(df[0:5])
# >>        0      1
# >> 0  Lorem    CSV
# >> 1  ipsum   Test
# >> 2  dolor    Say
# >> 3    sit  Hello
# >> 4  amet,  world
```

this would be a way to convert and combine string from pd.dataframe value for the last column using ' '.join()

```
print(df[5:][0].values)
# >> ['consectetur' 'adipiscing' 'elit']

print(' '.join(df[5:][0].values))
# >> consectetur adipiscing elit
```

since some of the string may have 'nan' value which cannot be use to join string with ' '.join(), so create new function to handle that.

```
def remove_nan(arr):
    return arr[~pd.isnull(arr)]
```

now, make a for loop to create a list for last column.

```
num_row = df.shape[1]
print(num_row)
# >> 2

last_col = []
for row in range(num_row):
    string_arr = df[5:][row].values
    string_arr = remove_nan(string_arr)
    last_col.append(' '.join(string_arr))
```

from last column that just created, make new pd.dataframe then combine it with df[0:5] using pd.concat and then tranpose again to get 6 columns data frame back as a result

```
newdf = pd.concat([df[0:5], pd.DataFrame(last_col).T], ignore_index = True).T
print(newdf)
# >>        0      1      2      3      4                            5
# >> 0  Lorem  ipsum  dolor    sit  amet,  consectetur adipiscing elit
# >> 1    CSV   Test    Say  Hello  world                  from python
```